# Python shlex.split(), ignore single quotes

Tags: python, split, quotes, shlex

How, in Python, can I use `shlex.split()` or similar to split strings, preserving only double quotes? For example, if the input is `"hello, world" is what 'i say'` then the output would be `["hello, world", "is", "what", "'i", "say'"]`.

Comment: It captures the entire double quoted string, but splits up the single quoted string.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. I don't get to write Python much these days, and I've never seen or used `shlex` before, so this was a fun one.

Comment: Python is really my job description these days

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import shlex

def newSplit(value):
    lex = shlex.shlex(value)
    lex.quotes = '"'
    lex.whitespace_split = True
    lex.commenters = ''
    return list(lex)

print newSplit('''This string has "some double quotes" and 'some single quotes'.''')
```

Comment: Only negligibly so, and the `lex.commenters` bit is actually something that my answer doesn't do. +1 for a different way to git-r-dun.

Comment: I started with the source code to the shlex.split function from the python source and just tweaked it with the list of quotes characters.

Comment: It took me a while, but this is slightly different than the normal shlex.split which passes posix ... [`shlex.shlex(value, posix=True)`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2a38df26e009/Lib/shlex.py#l274)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`shlex.quotes`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.shlex.quotes) to control which characters will be considered string quotes. You'll need to modify [`shlex.wordchars`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.shlex.wordchars) as well, to keep the `'` with the `i` and the `say`.

```
import shlex

input = '"hello, world" is what \'i say\''
lexer = shlex.shlex(input)
lexer.quotes = '"'
lexer.wordchars += '\''

output = list(lexer)
# ['"hello, world"', 'is', 'what', "'i", "say'"]
```

Comment: actually, this one failed on something else I was writing, and Peter's worked. thank you though!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what input did it fail on?

Comment: If the escaped quote is in the quoted section, is there a way forward? Say, `s = "1 'K\^o, Suzuk\'e'"` to split into `[1, "K\^o, Suzuk\'e"]`